# How to disable frontend side validation in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am trying this code but does not work.

```
$form=ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>
'id' => 'login-form',
'options' => ['class'=>'darkBg','enableClientValidation'=>false,'validateOnBlur' => false],
]); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['class'=>'form-control','type'=>'text','enableClientValidation'=>false,])->label(false) ?>
```

I wanted to disable Yii2 default error msg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add

```
->error(false)
```

This way no text is being shown, but field still gets marked red on failure.